# What balance issues would arise from a Chaotic Good Paladin?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, homebrew, balance, paladin, alignment

I have long been annoyed by the inability of Chaotic Good warriors to become empowered by their unwavering faith in freedom and human decency, and so am considering a custom archetype that would allow for Paladins to be either Lawful Good or Chaotic Good, with appropriate fluff/mechanical changes as necessary.

However, I am concerned that with the shift of alignment, certain options not available to Paladins now will become both available and abusable, and I would rather the custom archetype not get a reputation for being the world's most abusable build, particularly when it's being created for Role Play purposes instead of Roll Play.

---

**What abusable options would become available if a Paladin were to have a Chaotic Good alignment?**

---

Due to the archetype not being built yet, assume that the mechanics of Paladin do not change with the exception of anything mechanically tied to Law swapping to an exact equivalent tied to Chaos (Axiomatic to Anarchic, etc.).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Nothing Much.

As a GM, my houserules include changing the paladin to be any good (and antipaladins to be any evil) without needing an archetype for that change (Though I do change the code and any lawful aligned abilities to be chaotic or removed instead depending on alignment).

The biggest thing that it opens up for abuse is [Divine Fighting Technique: Way of the Shooting Star](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/divine-fighting-technique-combat/#Way_of_the_Shooting_Star):

> Way of the Shooting Star
>   Optional Prerequisite: A chaotic good bard of at least 2nd level can replace a versatile performance with the following initial benefit.
>
> Initial Benefit(s): You can add your Charisma bonus to attack rolls and damage rolls when wielding a starknife. If you do so, you don’t modify attack rolls and damage rolls with your starknife with your Strength modifier, your Dexterity modifier (if you have Weapon Finesse), or any other ability score (if you have an ability that allows you to modify attack rolls and damage rolls with that ability score).

Due to it using Charisma for attack and damage rolls, combined with [Divine Grace](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladiN/#Divine_Grace_Su), it tends to make it simple for the paladin to archetype as [Ioran Paladin](https://aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Paladin%20Iroran%20Paladin) or dip a level into [Nature](https://aonprd.com/MysteryDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Nature)/[Lunar](https://aonprd.com/MysteryDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Lunar)/[Lore](https://aonprd.com/MysteryDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Lore) oracle and get Charisma to Saves, AC, Attack, and Damage. While this is strong, it's been pretty much as easy to handle as a regular paladin in my games.

Comment: While I can't do much about Oradin multiclassing, it seems like it should be simple enough to prevent the Ioran archetype by changing the name and minorly altering the effect of one of the auras affected by the archetype. Also not a bad idea lore-wise, due to Ioran Paladin being based on Ioran Monks which are heavily tilted towards Law not Chaos.